# Filter $http request data before it is sent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

It seems Angular automatically strips properties prefixed with `$$`, e.g. `$$hashKey`, from request data / params objects.

I would like to exclude my own UI-only properties that I don't want sent to the server, but of course I don't want to use `$$`.

**Does Angular expose their `$$` filter method publicly in a way I can use it to filter my objects with a different prefix?**

And, where would be the best place to use this (or a custom) method? A Transform? An Interceptor?

Lets say this is my data object:

```
var payload = {
    id: 12345,   
    name: 'Bob',
    _editing: true
};
```

And I save it to the server like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/save',
    data: payload
});
```

How could I strip out the `_editing` property before the request is sent?

**EDIT:** Or any property starting with `_`

I need it to happen for all requests and it would need to work for deep, complex objects.

I'm using Angular v1.3.18

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use a `$httpProvider.interceptors`, but for the stripping part you can probably do something nice using [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
var o = {_f: 1, _b: 2, a: 1, b: 2 }

_.omit(o, function (value, key) { 
  return key.indexOf('_') === 0; 
});
```

This returns `{a: 1, b: 2}`.

**But** if you don't want to use an external library and just depend on Angular's utility kit, you could do:

```
angular.forEach(o, function (value, key) { 
  if (key.indexOf('_') === 0) { 
    delete o[key] 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a http Interceptor

In your config you just put this line in the app.js

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
})
```

And I created a factory like this

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', '$filter', function ($q, $rootScope, $filter) {
    var canceller = $q.defer();
    //some vars here
    return {

        request: function (config) {


            //Do some magic here
            //modify the header for example
            config.headers.someHeader = something;
            //or set a timeout if it takes too long
            config.timeout = 20000;

            return config || $q.when(config)
        },

        response: function (response) {

            //handle Response if you want           
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },

        responseError: function (response) {

            //handle error here if you want
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
}])
```

You can either access the config object and add or remove properties from the header or sent params or make a timeout and stuff, or access the response and do a broadcast or smth depends what you need

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok thanks, but do you know if Angular exposes their filter method that they use to strip their `$$` properties? Would be great if I could use a built-in solution

Comment: so you could just say if(config.data.editing.indexOf('_') > -1){do or dont do smth right?}but built in not sure

Answer (score 0):

You can just `delete` the properties from the payload before you call the `post`.

```
var payload = {
    id: 12345,   
    name: 'Bob',
    _editing: true
};

delete payload._editing

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/save',
    data: payload
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using interceptors to modify your request or response. As the name itself suggests, its job is to intercept a http request or response. Quoted from angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> For purposes of global error handling, authentication, or any kind of
>   synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or
>   postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept
>   requests before they are handed to the server and responses before
>   they are handed over to the application code that initiated these
>   requests.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);

app.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', function($q) {  

    var myInterceptor = {
        request: function(config) {
            delete config.data._editing;

            return config;
        }   
    };

    return myInterceptor;
}]);

app.controller('myController', ['$http', function($http) {
    var payload = {
        id: 12345,   
        name: 'Bob',
        _editing: true
    };

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: payload
    });
}]);
```

I have prepared a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3yp27wy/1/) for that. The fiddle does the ajax request, so check the network tab to see the request payload.